# SQL Query to add a new column after an existing column in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need a SQL query which add a new column after an existing column, so the column will be added in a specific order.

Please suggest me if any `ALTER` query which do that.

Comment: Which version of SQL? (MysQl, SQL Server, etc.)

Answer (score 82):

Microsoft SQL (AFAIK) does not allow you to alter the table and add a column after a specific column. Your best bet is using Sql Server Management Studio, or play around with either dropping and re-adding the table, or creating a new table and moving the data over manually. neither are very graceful.

[**MySQL**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) does however:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD COLUMN  new_column <type>
AFTER       existing_column
```

Answer (score 39):

It's possible.

First, just add each column the usual way (as the last column).

Secondly, in `SQL Server Management Studio` Get into Tools => Options.

Under 'Designers' Tab => 'Table and Database Designers' menu, uncheck the option 'Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation'.

Afterwards, right click on your table and choose 'Design'.
In 'Design' mode just drag the columns to order them.

Don't forget to save.

Comment: OP asked for SQL query to do it. your suggestion is using Management Studio.

Comment: +1 This helped me to get it done by turning off the "Prevent saving" option. Therefore don't need query (which isn't possible anyway).

Comment: thank you. you helped me fix the problem of updating table using designer

Comment: How do I favourite an answer instead of a question?  I know without a doubt, that I'll need to find this option again.

Answer (score 24):

ALTER won't do it because column order **does not matter** for storage or querying

If SQL Server, you'd have to use the SSMS Table Designer to arrange your columns, which can then generate a script which drops and recreates the table

Edit Jun 2013

Cross link to my answer here: [Performance / Space implications when ordering SQL Server columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692021/performance-space-implications-when-ordering-sql-server-columns/6692107#6692107)

Comment: Column order **does matter** when dealing with bulk insert.

Comment: Thanks.  Saved me wasting more time trying to figure out how to make the MS SQL product do this.

Comment: When exporting the results of ``SELECT * FROM some_table``, the order of columns does matter. The OP did not say why the question is important to him or her, so I consider this a less-than-perfect answer.

Comment: @gbn unless you are also inserting a file id or something similar while using openrowset(BULK

Answer (score 4):

If you want to alter order for columns in Sql server, There is no direct way to do this in SQL Server currently.

Have a look at http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/04/08/sql-server-change-order-of-column-in-database-tables/

You can change order while edit design for table.

Answer (score 3):

First add the new column to the old table through SSMStudio. Go to the database >> table >> columns. Right click on columns and choose *new column*. Follow the wizard.  Then create the new table with the columns ordered as desired as follows:

```
select * into my_new_table from (
select old_col1, my_new_col, old_col2, old_col3
from my_old_table 
) as A
;
```

Then rename the tables as desired through SSMStudio. Go to the database >> table >> choose rename.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research there is no way to do this exactly the way you want. You can manually re-create the table and copy the data, or SSMS can (and will) do this for you (when you drag and drop a column to a different order, it does this).
In fact it souldn't matter what order the columns are...
As an alternative solution you can select the data you want in the order you desired.
For example, instead of using asterisk (*) in select, specify the column names in some order...
Lets say **MyTable** has **col1, col2, col3, colNew** columns.

Instead of:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
```

You can use:

```
SELECT col1, colNew, col2, col3 FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score -8):

It is a bad idea to select * from anything, period. 
This is why SSMS adds every field name, even if there are hundreds, instead of select *.  It is extremely inefficient regardless of how large the table is. If you don't know what the fields are, its still more efficient to pull them out of the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database than it is to select *.

A better query would be:

```
SELECT 
 COLUMN_NAME, 
 Case 
  When DATA_TYPE In ('varchar', 'char', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'binary') 
  Then convert(varchar(MAX), CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH)  
  When DATA_TYPE In ('numeric', 'int', 'smallint', 'bigint', 'tinyint') 
  Then convert(varchar(MAX), NUMERIC_PRECISION) 
  When DATA_TYPE = 'bit' 
  Then convert(varchar(MAX), 1)
  When DATA_TYPE IN ('decimal', 'float') 
  Then convert(varchar(MAX), Concat(Concat(NUMERIC_PRECISION, ', '), NUMERIC_SCALE)) 
  When DATA_TYPE IN ('date', 'datetime', 'smalldatetime', 'time', 'timestamp') 
  Then '' 
 End As DATALEN, 
 DATA_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
Where 
 TABLE_NAME = ''
```

Comment: almost-downvoted as This does not directly answer the question.
But I think what you want to say is that the order matters only if you use a select *, which is mostly never necessary or good.